# What image does our new theme need for the 404 page?

Tags: discussion, theme

What image does our new theme need for the 404 page?

And in case you couldn't tell, we'll be launching soon enough.

Comment: e.g.: http://dba.stackexchange.com/404

Answer (score 2):

Some kind of "No data" or "0 rows(s) affected" message?

Answer (score 2):

Another idea..

A selection of message based on real life error messages?

> Data Monkeys has gone away
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to Data Monkeys

etc

Answer (score 1):

Thought: Can we still maybe get one or two guys assembling the logo?

Like the site is broken and they're fixing it? This would tie it into the main logo too. Just a thought.